# Sqlite3 memory management

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, ios5

Some times I am getting this kind of error in my app:

```
(3551,0xb0103000) malloc: *** error for object 0xd27ce60: Non-aligned pointer being freed (2)
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
(3551,0xb0353000) malloc: *** error for object 0x65676170: Non-aligned pointer being freed (2)
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
(3551,0xb0103000) malloc: *** error for object 0xd27cd40: Non-aligned pointer being freed (2)
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
(3551,0xb0353000) malloc: *** error for object 0x40640000: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
(3551,0xb0103000) malloc: *** error for object 0xd27cc20: Non-aligned pointer being freed (2)
```

This happens when i try to insert new info into sqlite:

```
  if ( sqlite3_exec(databaseHandle, [insertStatement UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &error) == SQLITE_OK)//exception
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else{
    {
```

databaseHandle object is static and I open database when app starts:

```
sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &databaseHandle) == SQLITE_OK)
```

Maybe I am missing something?

```
NSString *insertStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO INFORMATION (INFO) VALUES (\"%@\")",info];
```

Comment: That all looks good. Have you got an example of your insertStatement? Sounds like that string is going wrong.

Comment: i'm facing a [similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14462951/ios-using-the-same-sqlite-parameter-more-than-once-causes-premature-memory-deal) problem